# js-data dataStore.find() can't find cached results

Tags: angular, typescript, jsdata

I am calling `dataStore.find()` with the same parameters each time. The current adapter is the `HttpAdapter`. However, after the initial call, it does not seem to be able to find the data in the cache and makes a call to the API again. This is happening even though the data is in fact being cached, js-data just can't seem to find it:

[image: same record added each time]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data I was getting back from the API did not contain an `id` property. When js-data looks through the cache after a call to `dataStore.find()`, it looks for an item with a matching `idAttribute`, which is `id` by default. Thus, every time the data was requested, it was being added to the cache but could not be found afterwords. To fix this, I added the appropriate `idAttribute` to my mapper:

```
this.mapper = this.dataStore.defineMapper('community', {
  schema: this.communitySchema,
  endpoint: 'cm',

  // We don't have an 'id' property so the cached records won't be found.
  // Thus, we set the 'idAttribute' to 'code', which is the unique identifier
  // for communities.
  idAttribute: 'code'
});
```